# Rails: group :production do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Say you create a group in a Gemfile like this:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

E.g. see http://bundler.io/v1.3/groups.html

Where does the `group` keyword come from?

And where does the `:production` attribute come from?

Links would help.

Comment: `group` is provided by Bundler (just as `gem` is) as part of its DSL and the group name is user-defined. Usage of groups is detailed in the link you provided. Could you be more specific as to what you're looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`group` is a method that is provided by Bundler.  `:production` is just a name of a group.  The document that you linked explains this concept pretty well.  (Unless I'm completely misunderstanding your question...)

Comment: Looking at the docs there's no reference to the word `method` anywhere in that page. But your answer works for me.

Comment: 'method' is just another word for 'function' or 'routine' or 'procedure'.